# Getting Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, dynamic

Given an integer N denoting the Length of a line segment. you need to cut the line segment in such a way that the cut length of a line segment each time is integer either x , y or z. and after performing all cutting operation the total number of cutted segments must be maximum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<climits>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int count(int*dp,int x,int y,int z,int N)
{
    if(N==0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(N<0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(dp[N]!=INT_MAX)
    {
        return dp[N];
    }
        dp[N]=max(count(dp,x,y,z,x)+count(dp,x,y,z,N-x)
                ,max(count(dp,x,y,z,y)+count(dp,x,y,z,N-y),
                count(dp,x,y,z,z)+count(dp,x,y,z,N-z)));
    return dp[N];
}
int main() 
{
    //code
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int x,y,z;
        cin>>x;
        cin>>y;
        cin>>z;
        //cout<<x<<y<<z<<n;
        int*dp=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n+1);
      // int dp[n+1];
        dp[0]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            dp[i]=INT_MAX;
        }
        cout<<x<<y<<z<<n;
        cout<<count(dp,x,y,z,n)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Don't dump it on us.

Comment: First of all don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new[]` instead. Then learn to not use dynamic allocation at all in situations like this, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Lastly, while you might allocate enough space to use 1-based array (or vector) indexes, please avoid that as well as it might confuse just about everyone reading your code.

Comment: As for your problem, have you checked that your recursion isn't to deep? Do you get a crash for *all* input? Or only for some input?

Comment: `sizeof(int)*n+1` should be `sizeof(int)*(n+1)` if you want to allocate space for `n+1` integers. Your code is allocating enough space for 1 integer plus 1 extra byte.

Comment: Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB; SO is *not* a fix-my-code service.

Comment: And if you'd used `new int[n+1]` you wouldn't have had that problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Important remark about memor allocation in C++**

C++ is not C. `malloc()` should really be avoided in C++, because it doesn't take care of the object lifecycle and hence requires a [placement new](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/) when it is used for types that are not [trivially copiable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable).

C++ memory allocation should use [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) (or `make_unique` or `make_shared` in combination with smart pointers), when it is needed.

But the best is to avoid using memory allocation, and rely instead on the safer and more powerful [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), such as for example [vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

**Your issue**

This being said, `int` is trivially copyable, and all you need to make it work is to correct the size formula to `sizeof(int)*(n+1)`. It's because your loop goes until `n` included, so that your array has to hold `n+1` elements.

Comment: @user0042 ok, i wanted to remain simple to facilitate the OP transition from C to C++. But you are right and I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: I didn't DV your answer BTW.

Comment: @user0042 no problem at all ! Even if you would, a DV and some constructive critical comments are always helpful to improve quality of contributions. Thanks.